# Do objects have access to outer Lexical Environment?

Tags: javascript, closures

I was trying to find a solution for `counter(i)` function of [JS fun practice](https://github.com/zero-to-mastery/JS_Fun_Practice), and I ended up with this:

```js
function counter(start) {
  let count = start;
  return {
    up() {
      return ++count;
    },
    down() {
      return --count;
    },
  }
}

let obj = counter(10);
let {up, down} = obj;

console.log(up()); // 11
console.log(down()); // 10
console.log(down()); // 9
console.log(up()); // 10
```

At the first sight I thought there would be an error because objects don't have Lexical Environment. I thought neither `up()` nor `down()` would be able to access `count`. But when I tried to run the code, it worked!
I know how Lexical Environment works, and I wonder if there is a way for objects to access it.
When `counter` function returns the object there should be a link between the object and its Lexical Environment so that `up()` and `down()` can access `count`. Is there anything like that?

Comment: `let count` is available within the scope in which it is defined. Both `up()` and `down()` are defined in the same scope, and so they can see `count`.

Comment: Yes @David, you are absolutely right. But `counter` **returns** an object. I'm not working with the object in the function's body anymore. When a function is returned, it's in the same scope and it has a reference to outer closure via `[[Environment]]` property. That's how it accesses the outer context. But objects don't have such a property. I'm still learning so if I didn't catch your point, I would appreciate an article explaining it.

Comment: Yes, but you are not trying to reference `count` when you call `up()` or `down()`. They reference count themselves within their own scope, where count is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know how Lexical Environment works, and I wonder if there is a way for objects to access it.
> When counter function returns the object there should be a link between the object and its Lexical Environment so that up() and down() can access count. Is there anything like that?

Yes. Javascript supports 3 types of scopes:

1. Global
2. Function
3. **Block**

Anything within a pair of curly braces ( *{...}* ) forms a block in Javascript. Block scopes have their own lexical environment. So the object returned from `counter()` is a block which has reference to `counter()`'s lexical environment using which it can access the `count` variable.

The functions `up()` and `down()` form a closure and hence can access `count` even when invoked from global i.e. outside of `counter()`'s scope.

Comment: I didn't know block scopes have their own lexical environment which has a link to outer one. Thanks for your answer @Shraddha.